# Azure DevOps Pipeline conditional script arguments

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-devops, yaml, pipeline

Is it possible to conditionally add arguments to a script within a pipeline task, based on a value of a pipeline paramater?

Example:

```yaml
 parameters:
   - name: paramName
     displayName: DisplayName
     type: boolean
     default: trueasd

 steps:
 - task: PowerShell@2
   displayName: TaskName
   inputs:
     filePath: $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/someScript.ps1
     arguments:  -DefaultArg1 DefaultArg1_Value `
                 -DefaultArg2 DefaultArg2_Value
     ${{ if eq(parameters.paramName, 'false') }}:
                 -ConditionalParameter
```

`ConditionalParameter` is a `[switch]` parameter. The script which is called in `PowerShell@2` task is also meant for local use, which is why a `[switch]` parameter is much easier for the users, as you do not have to provide a value to it, as with `[boolean]` type, and the script **has a bunch of such parameters**.

Or will i have to change both the pipeline parameter and powershell script parameter types to `boolean`, as it is not possible to use a compile time pipeline expression in this case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not correct to set the condition in the value string of the input parameter on pipeline task.

To conditionally set the value of input parameter on pipeline task, you can do like as below.

```yaml
. . .

  - task: PowerShell@2
    displayName: 'TaskName'
    inputs:
      filePath: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/someScript.ps1'
      ${{ if eq(parameters.paramName, 'false') }}:
        arguments: >
          -DefaultArg1 DefaultArg1_Value
          -DefaultArg2 DefaultArg2_Value
          -ConditionalParameter
      ${{ else }}:
        arguments: >
          -DefaultArg1 DefaultArg1_Value
          -DefaultArg2 DefaultArg2_Value
```

For more details, you can reference the following documents:

- [**Expressions**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/expressions?view=azure-devops#conditionally-set-a-task-input)
- [**PowerShell v2 task**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/powershell-v2?view=azure-pipelines#call-powershell-script-with-multiple-arguments)

Comment: I knew about this way. It has the problem of completely redefining the whole `arguments` key. I have about 4 Parameters, each of which can be set or not, which would lead to way to many combinations for a *.yaml. This basically means, that i have to switch the type to `$bool`

Comment: Hi @Apolonius, I can understand that this may cause your YAML file to be quite verbose when you have many combinations of the arguments based on different conditions.
However, for your case, this is the only valid method supported in YAML pipeline on Azure DevOps, although it may look verbose in some situations.